# How To get values in Span Tag from JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a BMI Calculator using HTML. The inputs come from text fields. I am making some calculation with them in a Javascript function. I want to get the calculated values in a span like this:

```
<span id="" class="">Your Calculation Results is = </span>
<span id="" class="">   "" I want the result here ""    </span>
```

====================================================================
Edit : The part that i am asking about

```
<script language="javascript">
var bmi = document.getElementById("ID_bmiResult2").innerHTML;
bmi.value = weight / (heightInMeter * heightInMeter);
</script>

<body>
<span id="ID_bmiResult2">  </span>
</body>
```

i don't know how to make it ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Edit**: As it was pointed out, FF doesn't like `innerText`, so I'm replacing to `innerHTML` which in this particular case doesn't not change the overall functionality of the script.

You can get the 2nd `span` and pass the value directly to `innerHTML` like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('span')[1].innerHTML= 'the result';
```

**Note**: Consider using and `id` or `class` so you can find the exact element you need to change instead of retrieving several elements of that type (in this case `span`).
If you had an `id`, it would be like this:

```
document.getElementById('the id goes here').innerHTML= 'the result';
```

**Edit2**: This edit was made after the OP changed his question
It got really confusing now that I'm seeing your code.
I've written [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/Qa4AC/) so you can see it working

Comment: that would replace the text already in the span, not add to it.

Comment: @jackwanders: It does not seem like the span contains any other content.

Comment: @FelixKling my mistake, I misread his code; thought he wanted the result inside the first span.

Comment: `innerText` is not supported in Firefox. For the best compatibility, use `innerHTML` or both, `innerText` and `textContent`.

Comment: Yes, it would replace the text. Image the result (whatever it is) changes 3 times while the user is interacting, would you rather have 3 values *added* or only the latest calculated result?

Comment: @FelixKling good point. I'll edit to update `innerHTML` instead

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe i make it like that <span id="result"> </span>...... var bmi=a+b; .......... document.getElementById('result').innerHTML= 'bmi';...............................it doesn't work ??

Comment: @Mahmoud `bmi` is the actual result value now, so you don't need to use single quotes. Just pass it like this: `document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = bmi.toString();`

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe : I've edit the question above ,,, that what am trying to do but i can't reach to a solution .... :)

Comment: @Mahmoud check the fiddle in my Edit2

Answer (score 2):

If you have a variable like `calcResult`, you can do:

```
document.getElementById('spanId').innerHTML += calcResult;
```

Of course, that only works once. If you do it again, you'll have two results in the span. If you want to be able to change the result if the form fields change, I'd try:

```
<span id="calc">Your calculation result = <span></span></span>

var result = 12;
document.getElementById('calc').getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML = result;
```

Comment: on a second reading of your question, this answer addresses a slightly different version of your question. I'll leave it up anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Jquery](http://jquery.com/) ?

```
$("span").next().text("Your Result");

OR

$("span").eq(1).text("Your Result");
```

To do a better code, put a ID in your component.

Comment: JQuery is a great library, but it is totally unecessary for this task unless the OP is already using it.  Please refrain form jQuery-only answers on questions that don't mention or tag jQuery.  (jQuery-suplemented answers are okay, provided they include a complete non-jQuery answer as well, OR the task at hand is outlandishly difficult to complete without the use of a JavaScript library.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use document.writeln to get your result.  check out the fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net/CmVww/ to play with it.  Below are the results.

```
<div id="start">
<span id="one" class="sText">Your Calculation Results is = </span>
<span id="two" class="result">  
<script type="text/javascript">
var tst = 'I want the result here';
  document.writeln(tst);
</script>
</span>
```

Comment: `document.write` will *clear the entire contents of the page* and replace it with the value of `var`.  The OP wants to write to a specific element.

Comment: How is this not writing to the specific element?  Am I reading the question wrong?

Comment: @NicholasDecker I see that your fiddle works but your answer remains incorrect (`document.write(var)`??)

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe - Can you explain to me what is wrong?  I have it working in the fiddle.  When you say 'is wrong' do you mean that the answer is correct but I don't have the right information in the space above, or do you think you could help me out and explain a little more?

Comment: Your code in the answer is incorrect, just copy and paste what you have in your fiddle to here and I'll be able to change my vote (SO doesn't allow to change votes unless the answer is edited)

Comment: Thank you.  I am fairly new to this and would like to learn best way to do.  I had var meaning a variable but I see that a more specific answer is the correct way to do it.  Thanks @MilkyWayJoe

Comment: It's all good bud; btw, if you're new to SO, I suggest you to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var bmi = weight / (heightInMeter * heightInMeter);
document.getElementById('ID_bmiResult2').innerHTML= bmi;
```

Answer (score 0):

For calculate the bmi in javascript

```
<script language="javascript">

    var Height = 0;
    var Weight = 0;
    var BMI = 0;
    function getTotalBMIScore() {

        Height = document.getElementById('MainContent_txtPDHeight').value;
        //alert(Height + 'Height');
        Weight = document.getElementById('MainContent_txtPDWeight').value;
        //alert(Weight + 'Weight')
        BMI = Weight / (Height * Height);

        BMI = BMI.toFixed(2);

        //alert(BMI + 'BMI');
        document.getElementById('BMIScore').innerText = BMI;


    }

</script>
```

// end function

// if you are taking from textbox you should use this 
 Height(In meter):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPDHeight" onchange ="getTotalBMIScore()"   onKeyUp ="getTotalBMIScore()" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"  runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<span>
```

Weight(In kg):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPDWeight" onchange = "getTotalBMIScore()"  onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;"  onKeyUp ="getTotalBMIScore()" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

//if you want to display in span use this BMI:

```
<span id="BMIScore"></span></span><br />
```