# How to get the value from HTML code using javascript?

Tags: javascript

My js code are given belowbelow:

```
var intime = document.getElementById('clocktime').innerHTML;
```

using this I am getting the value of intime is below :

```
<span class="clocktime">07:25:41 PM</span>
```

I just want the value like **`07:25:41 PM`** from the code.How can I get this value using js?Any Idea?

Comment: look here for a detail information. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266990/how-to-get-values-in-span-tag-from-js

Answer (score 2):

This works in IE9+

```
document.querySelector('.clocktime').textContent;
```

Here’s an example: http://jsfiddle.net/bpWP4/

As T.J. Crowder pointed out, you can use `innerHTML` to make it work in IE8+.

```
document.querySelector('.clocktime').innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('clocktime')[0].innerHTML;
```

If you want IE 8 compatibility:

```
document.querySelector('.clocktime')[0].innerHtml; // Take note of the added period in the selector.
```

Both of these samples use a function that returns a array of elements matching the selector. That's why I use `[0]` to get the first element from those arrays.

Comment: (geez, I should know this stuff... jQuery's made me lazy / sloppy)

Comment: Nah, you're just using your mind for things that matter, rather than silly browser incompatibilities a whole team is keeping track of for us. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could grab the `<span>` instead of the element that surrounds it. For example:

```
var intime = document.querySelectorAll('#clocktime .clocktime')[0].innerHTML;
```

This assumes there's only one `<span class="clocktime">` inside the element with `id="clocktime"`.

But note that `querySelectorAll` isn't supported in IE 7, or really old versions of Firefox and Opera:

- http://caniuse.com/#search=queryselectorall